# Excel TRIMMEANIFS() alternative

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm currently using AVERAGEIFS() to get a mean for a selected range of data. I'd like to trim outliers from this (get an interquartile mean), but there's no TRIMMEANIFS statement.

Is there a way to emulate this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, you need to use an array formula - something like this

```
=TRIMMEAN(IF(A1:A5="dog",IF(ISNUMBER(B1:B5),B1:B5)),0.5)
```

Type it in and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> - it will have curly brackets around it.